# ToggleButtonBar - how to change color for only one button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a tooglebuttonbar (with 4 buttons) and I'd like to change the color of only one or two button according particular data.
Is someone has experience to do that.

I try to do like that

```
 var child:Button;
   child = Button(tbbAction2.getChildAt(0));
child.setStyle('color', '#CC33CC');
```

But there's no effect.

Comment: Where do you place your code?

Comment: I load the window with toogle bar. After I launch a httpservice to see  if the customer corresponding to specific criteria. Then in event result I place the part of code you can seen on my post. Thanks

Comment: I've tested this code. It works.  1. Do you know that the `color` property changes only text color, not color of the whole button? It was difficult for me to distinguish '#CC33CC' from default color. 2. Are you shure that you set your style after Flex call `updateDisplayList()`?

Comment: As you suggest I change my code by       child.setStyle('borderColor', '#FF070B'); but effect is same no change visible. I don't understand the second part of you answer can you explain please. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is several steps in flex component's life (search for on Google "flex component life cycle"). If you set any property you should be shure that the component is completely created. In other cases Flex changes your settings to default values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to extend ToggleButtonBar and / or the skins. In the skin you should be able to check the data and display the color based on the value of the data. Or create a second state in the skin that has the color you want. Depending on your values you would switch to the second state.